# Query from user and report table in Mysql

Tags: mysql

```
 User Table   
 ------------
| id | Name |
|------------
| 1  |  A   |
| 2  |  B   |
| 3  |  C   |
| 4  |  D   |
 ------------

 report Table   
 --------------------
| id | uid | status |
|--------------------
| 1  |  1   |   0   |
| 2  |  3   |   1   |   
| 3  |  2   |   0   |
| 4  |  3   |   1   |
 --------------------
```

Suppose I have two table user and report. I want to make a query on report table based on status column i.e

> WHERE status=0

But my problem is i don't want uid, i want user name from user table but how to do it? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

**JOIN syntax**

```
SELECT
    User.id,
    User.Name
FROM
    User
    JOIN report
        ON User.id=report.uid
WHERE
    report.status=0
```

**EXISTS syntax**

```
SELECT
    User.id,
    User.Name
FROM
    User
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        NULL
    FROM
        report
    WHERE
        report.status=0
        AND User.id=report.uid
)
```

**IN syntax**

```
SELECT
    User.id,
    User.Name
FROM
    User
WHERE User.id IN
(
    SELECT
        report.uid
    FROM
        report
    WHERE
        report.status=0
)
```

Reference:

- [13.2.8.2 JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)
- [13.2.9.6 Subqueries with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)
- [expr IN (value,...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  User.Name 
FROM 
  User 
  JOIN report 
    ON User.id=report.uid 
WHERE 
  report.status=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `INNER JOIN` like

```
SELECT u.id,
       u.Name
FROM USER u
INNER JOIN report r ON u.id=r.uid
WHERE r.status=0;
```